# Issues with multiprocessing in python hosted in Apache

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask, wsgi

I am having issues with running multiple processes in ptyhon on windows when hosted in wsgi/Apache. Same code works fine when running it in Flask self hosted environment by running it from command prompt.

Snippet for calling Method:

```
     # Start the processer
        print("Before creating Process")
        p = Process(target=self.worker, args=(task_reader, result_writer, pipeline_location_chunks[process_number],))
        print("Before starting process")

        #p= Process(target=self.Testworker)
        p.start()
```

**Definition for worker method**

```
def worker(self, task_reader, result_writer, pipeline_locations):
        """This is the method run by each sub-process. When initialized it loads its share of
        classifier pipelines into memory and sends True back to the start function to inform
        that it is ready for classification tasks"""
        # Load the pipelines in a dictionary with category number as key
        print("In Worker method")
        pipelines = {}
        for pipeline_location in pipeline_locations:
            category = int(pipeline_location.strip('.p'))
            pipelines[category] = pickle.load(open(self.pipeline_dir + pipeline_location, 'rb+'))

        # Inform the start function that this process's pipelines are done loading
        print("before sending")
        result_writer.send(True)

        # Wait for tasks. If a new task (sent by the classify function) is received,
        # run each pipeline's decision function and append it to a list of results
        # to send back to the classify function
        while True:
            # Get tasks (if any) from this process's task queue. If there are none, this process's
            # flow blocks here until there is a task available
            new_task = task_reader.recv()
            print("after receiving")
            results = []
            for category, pipeline in pipelines.items():
                result = pipeline.decision_function(new_task)
                tup = (category, result[0])
                results.append(tup)
            # Send the list of results back to the classify function
            result_writer.send(results)
```

When I run this code in apache, it starts the process but does not print the first line added in worker method. I have added this logging intentionally to verify that multiprocessing is working fine. Please let me know how I can make it functional as I need to deploy it on production.

Environment details:
Flask 0.11
Python 3.5
Apache 2.4.23 (64 bit)

Comment: What apache module are you using to serve your WSGI application? is it `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: after ```p.start()``` try calling ```p.join```.

Comment: I tried calling p.join() but it did not help as well. Yes, I am using mod_wsgi version mod_wsgi-4.4.23+ap24vc14-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64